# Sending mail issues. very confusing

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

Hi my name is what, my name is who.. ops got carried away

Now this might be a serverfault question and a stackoverflow question but I will go with it here because I don't really know the answer.

I been sending mail a lot with asp.net before and never had problems like this before.
I have setup a mail with this following code

```
var list = new List<string> { "mail", "mail", "mail", "mail" };

        var smtp = new SmtpClient("localhost", 25);
        var plainText = txtPlain.Text;
        var htmlText = Server.HtmlDecode(FCKeditor1.Value);

        foreach (var email in list)
        {
            var message = new MailMessage()
                          {
                              From = new MailAddress("my server mail"),
                              ReplyTo = new MailAddress("mail")
                          };

            var mailMessage = Server.HtmlDecode(FCKeditor1.Value);
            message.To.Add(email);
            message.Subject = "title";
            message.Body = mailMessage;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2");

            var alternateViewHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlText, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
            var alternateViewPlainText = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(plainText, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

            message.AlternateViews.Add(alternateViewHtml);
            message.AlternateViews.Add(alternateViewPlainText);

            smtp.Send(message);
        }
```

now the issue becomes that some email clients get just plain while some get the html.
Like on my hotmail on the computer i get the html but on my iphone i get the plain one. 
Why is that?

and like that wasn't enough The mail wont deliver to some mails like any .pl email. Now here is where I am thinking that it might be a reverse DNS setup thing on my windows server 2008 issue , i had same issue with hotmail but that was solved when I added the plain. Anybody have had the problem before?

I am very thankful for any answer I get.. thanks

**EDIT**  some company mails, it becomes spam / Got answer gone look it up, please feel free to inform me more

Comment: You have no (direct) influence on the spam rating of your recipients. I might consider everything with the word "apple" spam - there's nothing you can do about it. Ask the (opt-in, I hope) recipients for the setup of their spam protection. Most allow the admins to see the criterias that lead to the bad classification.

Comment: Must be an issue with your SMTP server. Especially so, if the emails are considered spam.

Comment: @Benjamin Ok I could ask that, thanks

@Dercsár Yes I thought so to but then some do let mail pass just fine and some other don't. so I am a little confused whit that.

But the main issues is the other problems I got like why some get plain some get html, even on the same mail address but just different device (like mobile)

Comment: I agree with Benjamin and Dercsár. All this sounds like problems of the recipient SMTP server *and* the mail viewer of the client. The viewer decides if he prefers Plain-Text or HTML, and the receiving Server decides if it is Spam or not.

Comment: @bobby thanks for your answer. Anybody got an Idea why I can not send email to a .pl?

Comment: @Dejan.S: Does an error message occur or is it delivered and the pl-server swallows it?

Comment: it is delevered as all the other mails. just dont come though to the receiver

Comment: The problem with the .pl was because the spam filter did not let the mail through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a HTML Version of the Message in the `Message.Body` and set the `IsBodyHtml = true`
So why are you duplicating the html component a second time, buy sending a HTML Alternative view... I think this might be redundant. try removing the two lines

```
        message.Body = mailMessage;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Also, double check those `MediaTypeNames.Text.PROPERTY` values and ensure they are returning  `text/plain` and `text/html`

http://www.andreas-kraus.net/blog/tips-for-avoiding-spam-filters-with-systemnetmail/

Comment: It was just a mistype by me when I put the code on here, I did remove that. thanks for the link and tip